# Bootstrap: Background colour 100% screen width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background

I'm trying to create a fairly simple website in bootstrap. I'd like each section to have its own background colour similar to what is done here: https://flaticons.co/. Do you happen to know if there's a class or css styling that will allow the background to be 100% width?

```
<div id="main" class="container">
        <section class="row">
            <p class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" col-sm-push-7><img src="images/an_image.gif"></p>
            <h1 class="col-md-8 col-sm-6" col-sm-pull-7>Some content...</h1>
        </section>

        <!-- ===== background colour wanted here 100% window width===== -->
        <section id="about" class="row">
            <div>
                <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
                <p>Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

-----------This works:

Guys! Guys!

Thanks for those answers. They're great for when bootstrap isn't involved. When bootstrap IS involved... this works. So many divs :( But it's working great!

```
<div class="secondary">
     <section class="row container">
          <div class="row">
               <p class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" col-sm-push-7><img src="images/temp_riley.gif"></p>
                <h1 class="col-md-8 col-sm-6" col-sm-pull-7>Hi. I'm Riley: a problem solving UX designer (and front-end developer) who is intrigued by change and loves a good challenge. </h1>
          </div>
     </section>
```

```
css: 

.secondary {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: This is where you need to look at the hierarchy of an XML document like a HTML page. Your very first div is a container for the "sections" within, right? To do a specific "100% width" for the second section in your example (and keep the styles correct for the section above" you will need to look at putting the second section inside its very own container BELOW (and outside) the current container. You can then style the new container to be 100% wide and have a background colour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an element 100% the screen width in CSS you can use the following:

```
width: 100vw;
```

The `vw` stands for view width. This is new to CSS3. [See here](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) for compatibility in browsers (Current browsers almost universally support it).

Comment: This is a wonderful trick that's a bit more elegant than the div, div, div I finally figured out! :) THanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your simple example, setting the width of each section and div to 100% will stretch them across your browser's window. Here's a fiddle showing what you're looking for, http://jsfiddle.net/MPQVu/, but the basic idea at play is:

```
.parent_div { width: 100%; }

.child_div { width: 100%; }
```